# Fatal error: can't find PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_PDB_DefaultDatabaseConnection in testcase.php

Tags: php, phpunit

So I am trying to do some database testing in phpunit, and when trying to connect to the database, i get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_DefaultDatabaseConnection' not found in D:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\Extensions\Database\TestCase.php on line 145
```

I opened up testcase.php and checked line 145. This is line 143-146:

```
protected function createDefaultDBConnection(PDO $connection, $schema = '')
{
   return new PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_DefaultDatabaseConnection($connection, $schema);
}
```

Also, heres the getConnection function i used, incase something is wrong with it:

```
public function getConnection() {
    if ($this->conn === null) {
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
            $this->conn = $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, 'test');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    return $this->conn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the Database extension. Issue the following commands in the console:

```
sudo pear config-set auto_discover 1
sudo pear install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/DbUnit
```

(On Windows you need to omit the `sudo` and probably locate the path to pear.exe)

Comment: i alredy did that, says i alredy got 1.3.1 installed.

Comment: Uninstall it and install again, but don't miss `--alldeps`

Comment: did pear uninstall phpunit/DbUnit and install --alldeps pear.phpunit.de/DbUnit
still same error

Comment: What gives you `php -r "echo ini_get('include_path');"` ?

Comment: Does the file `D:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Extensions\Database\DB\DefaultDatabaseConnection.php` exist?

Comment: Do you have `require_once 'PHPUnit\Extensions\Database\DB\DefaultDatabaseConnection.php';` in the code?

Comment: no i did not have it, i tried adding it but the error still exists

Comment: Does the file D:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Extensions\Database\DB\DefaultDatabaseConnection.php **really** exist? Or does D:\xampp\php\PHPUnit\Extensions\Database\DB\DefaultDatabaseConnection.php exist?

Comment: D:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit\Extensions\Database\DB\DefaultDatabaseConnection.php does exist, the second doesnt tho. The phpunit dirrectory does not exist in D:\xampp\php\

Comment: Hmm, then I can't help further anymore. I guess you have a typo somewhere or some doubled or missing configuration. Use Linux in favour of that xampp crap! ;)